# как разбить число на три части

Tags: c#

Есть нумерация которая состоит из номера+месяц+год
то-есть 1062020, необходимо отобразить вот так 1/06/2020, номер може быть и такой вот 10000/06/2020

Comment: Почему 1/06/2020, а не 10/6/2020?

Comment: месяц обозначается двумя символами то-есть номер документа/месяц/год

Comment: @return, минус может поставить любой и не факт, что вам ответит минусующий. Но как по мне, вы взяли простую задачу и усложнили её в десятки раз, если не в сотни.

Comment: @AlexKrass можно вам вопрос, что в моём ответе не так (я сам не понимаю, на нём 2 минуса и 1 плюс)?

Comment: Задача звучит так. На вход подается строка из цифр вида "xxxxxyyzzzz", где xxxxx - номер документа неограниченной длины, yy - месяц, zzzz - год. Надо преобразовать в "xxxxx/yy/zzzz". Решается она в тупую одной строкой кода, а дальше автор сам решит, как её встроить в свой код: `String formatted = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", s.Substring(0, s.Length-6), s.Substring(s.Length-6, 2), s.Substring(s.Length-4));`. К тому же этот код более понятный, чем ваш с битовыми операциями, а для кода это в 90% случаев важнее производительности.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Yevhenii я сделал это по всем критериям, посмотри мой ответ ниже, я изменил алгоритм

Comment: @AlexKrass с каких пор побитовые операции сложны? Да и задача не в сложности кода, а в его реализации. Я смог уместить номер документа в `long`. Написал парсер. Мне кажется, что подавать на вход данные ввиде `1/06/2020` более корректно чем `1062020`. Так хотя бы понятно где номер, месяц, год.

Comment: @AlexKrass ваше решение не эффективно: оно создаёт 3 новых объекта в куче при *каждом* парсинге.

Comment: @return, с тех самых пор, как нужно анализировать, что они делают и высчитывать. В тоже время Substring говорит сам за себя, тут думать вообще не надо. Это позволяет не отвлекаться на понимание реализации мелких задач и концентрироваться на больших. И чем больше проект, тем это важнее. Вы экономите на спичках. Ну да, вы выиграли пару тиков и пару байт, жаль никто этого не заметит. А вот читающий ваш код коллега спасибо точно не скажет. Нужно четко понимать, где нужна производительность и где её можно выкинуть в пользу удобств.

Comment: @AlexKrass ну, тут не "пара байтов", а 28 * 3 = 84 байта + дата каждый раз, когда вы вызываете метод. Только были внедрены `Span` и `Memory`, как консерваторы сказали `Substring`. Если грамотно делить методы, то всё будет нормально. Да, на уровне приложения можно так баловаться (вон Unity вообще `string` вместо `enum` юзает), но это не код приложения – он может быть где угодно. И не просто так добавляли для него `Span`, `Memory`, `ConfigureAwait` и т. д.

Comment: @return, вы все еще пытаетесь экономить там, где от этого не будет толку. Ваш второй ответ я понимаю, он имеет смысл. А то, что вы написали в качестве первого, просто переусложнение. А еще будет ли он работать на старых версиях C#? ))

Comment: @AlexKrass а вы пытаетесь натянуть сову на глобус. Написание `struct DocumentNumber` – это "низкий" уровень. Когда этот тип используют на более высоком уровне, то они ждут от него, что он будет работать быстро и, т. к. это `struct`, не будет жрать память. Мой `struct` (кроме `ToString`) удолетворяет этим требованиям. Не нужно писать "высокоуровневыми" `Substring`'ами или `new byte[]`'ами "low-level" и не нужно писать так как я на "high-level"!

Comment: @AlexKrass давайте не использовать `Task`, ведь в C# 1.0 его не было и он не будет поддерживаться на Windows XP... Давайте вообще не использовать C#, не будем писать на си и даже на ассембли, ведь ваш C# код **потенциально** может не поддерживаться на компах из 60-х!

Comment: @return есть куча проектов, которые вышли всего 5-10 лет назад и которые надо дорабатывать, что я по вашему должен ответить заказчику? Извините - вы устарели, я не могу написать для вас код, мы ведь современная компания и идем в ногу со временем? Опять же, вы для простой операции пишите целую структуру - бритва Оккама вам в помощь. Вы что-то там экономите, отлично, а оно имеет смысл? Сколько я должен породить объектов в памяти, чтобы пользователь это почувствовал? К сожалению это сайт вопросов-ответов, тут не ведутся подобные споры и формат не позволяет. Но вы меня спросили, я ответил.

Comment: @return вы перегнули палку. если это "legacy" то не нужно его переписывать код не "legacy" код. я про новый проект, а не про "старьё. Как он собирается хранить номер документа? с помощью кортежа?? хорошо. тогда типы `RuntimeMethodHandle`, ... не нужны – юзайте `IntPtr`. Ну нужны `DateTime`. Зачем, ведь это `long`, да и зачем `long`??? Ведь это надо переводить ожно в другое... Лучше создать `class DateTime` с туевой хучей полей типа `int` и гордиться: я написал *`high-level`* код! зачем вообще нужны `struct`'ы, если их нельзя нормально в `object`... это не какой-нибудь JS. Это C#.

Comment: @return вы что-то там эмоционально написали, но доводов это не отражает. Не, я как бы понимаю, что вы хотите сказать - но считаю это бессмысленным. Ну да, это C# и он способен перемолоть подобный код не глядя. Вы хотите писать быстрый и эффективный код в ущерб читабельности - хорошо. Вот только принято делать наоборот, если по итогу производительность и эффективность не дает никаких **реальных преимуществ**, кроме цифр на бумаге. И да, код написанный всего-лишь год назад, это не такое уж старье. Я перенесу обсуждение в чат, а то мы нафлудили и так уже порядочно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109238/discussion-between-alex-krass-and-return).

Answer (score 2):

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    // checks

    var buffer = stackalloc char[input.Length + 2]; // potential stack overflow

    input[..^8].CopyTo(buffer);
    input[^8] = '/';
    input[^7..^5].CopyTo(buffer.Slice(^7));
    input[^5] = '/';
    input[^4..^0].CopyTo(buffer.Slice(^4));

    Console.WriteLine(buffer.ToString());
}
```

Ну или "в одну строчку":

```cs
$"{s[..^8]}/{s[^7..^5]}/{s[^4..^0]}";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static string BrokeDigit(string word)
{
  string compiledString = "";
  var lengthOfWord = word.Length;
  var numberOfDocumentArray = lengthOfWord - (6 + 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfWord; i++)
  {
    if (i <= numberOfDocumentArray)
    {
      compiledString += word[i];

      if (i == numberOfDocumentArray)
      {
        compiledString += '/';
      }
    }

    else if (i >= numberOfDocumentArray && i < (numberOfDocumentArray + 3))
    {
      compiledString += word[i];

      if (i == (numberOfDocumentArray + 2))
      {
        compiledString += '/';
      }
    }

    else
    {
      compiledString += word[i];
    }
  }


  return compiledString;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var compiledDate = BrokeDigit(Console.ReadLine());
  Console.WriteLine(compiledDate);
}
```

Ввожу: `1000003202540`
Выводит: `1000003/20/2540`

P.s.: я переделал прогу под свой новый алгоритм

Алгоритм, если надо:

1. Я получил длину вводных данных.
2. Я из всей длины вычел длину года(4 #1997), и длину месяца(2 #07 ).
3. Я получил длину номера. Всё оставшееся - это год и месяц.
4. Я прописал длину номера, и когда индекс был последний, я выводил этот символ, потом добавил '/'.
5. Дальше, я добавлял два символа(месяц), и когда был последний, добавлял '/'.
6. Потом оставшееся я просто добавил, без каких либо модификаций.
7. (150050/07/1997) - первое - номер, второе - месяц, третье - год. Длина всего числа(150050071997) - 12 символов(последний - 11 индекс).

Comment: @return я это понимаю, но в месяце разве есть 10000 дней?) так что, огромного смысла нет. Когда я увидел "У вашего алгоритма" я прям обрадовался что это мой первый алгоритм, хоть я и новичёк.)))

Comment: первое число - это не номер дня, это номер документа

Comment: @Mr_CatYT Прочитайте ещё раз задачу, первая цифра - это не дни )

Comment: Нуу, тогда эта задача у меня решается только на Python, а не c# :3 Ладно, в голове придумал алгоритм, щас сделаю

Comment: я сделал новый алгоритм

Comment: @Mr_CatYT На Питоне это всё элементарно в одну строчку делается )

Comment: @CrazyElf поэтому я и сказал что легче будет это сделать на змейке)

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, проще всего это будет сделать при помощи регулярного выражения:

```
var pattern = @"(\d+?)(\d{2})(\d{4})$";
var replacement = "$1/$2/$3";
var number = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Comment: задача же была отобразить а не спарсить)

Comment: да и парсинг через regex... ну типо можно, но типо и не очень... (возможно это вкусовщина, но по моему лучше не полениться и написать "нормальный" (оптимизированный) парсер)

Comment: @return для того, чтобы отобразить, надо сначала правильно спарсить ))

Comment: или инициализировать через код (так или иначе, он не писал, что это нужно спарсить)

Comment: @return думаете, пару страниц кода вместо одного regexp-а написать - это очень и очень? ))

Comment: тут не пара страниц

Comment: щас напишу и парсер в моём ответе (всё таки взяли на "слабо" :) )

Comment: А, похоже я неправильно таки понял задачу, в исходном номере только цифры. Ну тогда regex ещё проще

Comment: Я написал парсер и сравнил их скорость (делал 3 замера по 1 000 000 оп.): парсер – 168 мкс (0,000168 мс), regex – 3 010 нс. В 18 раз быстрее.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109234/discussion-between-crazyelf-and-return).

Comment: по-моему тут и так всё ясно))))

Answer (score -1):

```cs
// default value: `1/00/0000`
public readonly struct DocumentNumber : IEquitable<DocumentNumer>
{
    readonly int numIndex;
    readonly int date;

    public int Number => numIndex + 1;
    public int Year => date & 0x3fff; // 1..14 bits
    public int Month => date >> 14; // 15..18 bits
    public DateTime Date => new DateTime(Year, Month, 0);

    public DocumentNumber(int number, DateTime date)
    {
        if (number < 1) /*throw*/;

        numIndex = number - 1;
        this.date = (date.Month << 14) | date.Year;
    }

    // ...

    public override string ToString() => $"{Number}/{Month:D2}/{Year:D4}";
    public static bool TryParse(ReadOnlySpan<char> buffer, out DocumentNumber number)
    {
        number = default;

        if (buffer.Length < 9) return false;
        if (buffer[^5] != '/' ||
            buffer[^8] != '/') return false;

        if (!int.TryParse(buffer[^4..^0], out var year)) return false;
        if (!int.TryParse(buffer[^7..^5], out var month)) return false;
        if (!int.TryParse(buffer[..^8], out var num)) return false;

        number = new DocumentNumber(num, new DateTime(year, month, 1));

        return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Если сделать поле `date` публичным:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var docNum = new DocumentNumber(3, DateTime.Now);

    // binary view
    var date = docNum.date;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        Console.Write((((date << i) & 0x20000) >> 17) != 0 ? '1' : '0');

    Console.Write(' ');

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        Console.Write((((date << i) & 0x2000) >> 13) != 0 ? '1' : '0');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь